# Draggable borderless window in CefSharp

Tags: c#, drag, cefsharp, borderless

I want to implement borderless window with drag logic on some HTML element. I found some working examples (like [frameless window for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frameless-window-sample/hjjdaddngnaofnfjpajdcbdmkegiakec)) and this is what I've tried:

```
.title-area 
{
   -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

<div class='title-area'>
    A draggable area
</div>
```

Then, in C# code I've implemented IDragHandler class:

```
internal class PromtDragHandler : IDragHandler
{
    bool IDragHandler.OnDragEnter(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IDragData dragData, DragOperationsMask mask)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void IDragHandler.OnDraggableRegionsChanged(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IList<DraggableRegion> regions)
    {

    }
}
```

Method OnDraggableRegionsChanged fires once at start, OnDragEnter fires when I'm dragging some text of the element "title-area". But I'm not sure what to do next to make my window move?

**UPDATE.** As mentioned in comments, [CefTestApp](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/77746cfd1b863753ba05811cae89d2e79204cdb6/tests/cefclient/?at=master) support this drag feature. In the source code we have method OnSetDraggableRegions which is called from DragHandler:

```
void RootWindowWin::OnSetDraggableRegions(
const std::vector<CefDraggableRegion>& regions) {
REQUIRE_MAIN_THREAD();

// Reset draggable region.
  ::SetRectRgn(draggable_region_, 0, 0, 0, 0);

  // Determine new draggable region.
  std::vector<CefDraggableRegion>::const_iterator it = regions.begin();
  for (;it != regions.end(); ++it) {
    HRGN region = ::CreateRectRgn(
        it->bounds.x, it->bounds.y,
        it->bounds.x + it->bounds.width,
        it->bounds.y + it->bounds.height);
    ::CombineRgn(
        draggable_region_, draggable_region_, region,
        it->draggable ? RGN_OR : RGN_DIFF);
    ::DeleteObject(region);
  }

  // Subclass child window procedures in order to do hit-testing.
  // This will be a no-op, if it is already subclassed.
  if (hwnd_) {
    WNDENUMPROC proc = !regions.empty() ?
        SubclassWindowsProc : UnSubclassWindowsProc;
    ::EnumChildWindows(
        hwnd_, proc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(draggable_region_));
  }
}
```

I'm still not quite understanding, how exactly information about dragable regions (which fires only once at start) helps to move window? Can someone explain me this logic or provide C# equivalent of this code?

Comment: Check the `cefclient` example app, from memory there's a working example that you should be able to port over. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/77746cfd1b863753ba05811cae89d2e79204cdb6/tests/cefclient/?at=master

Comment: @amaitland, yes you are right - it does support grag feature (at least windows app). But I don't understand how exactly it's working. I've updated my question.

Comment: Try debugging the code, see it in action to see how it works

Comment: @amaitland, done. Check the source if you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, it would probably be better if you posted as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE2. I DID IT.** This is what I've added to my form code:

```
IntPtr DragableRegionNative = Native.CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);

    void RegionsChangedCallback(DraggableRegion[] Regions)
    {

        Native.SetRectRgn(DragableRegionNative, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (Regions == null)
            return;

        foreach (var Region in Regions)
        {
            var RegionNative = Native.CreateRectRgn(
                Region.X, Region.Y,
                Region.X + Region.Width,
                Region.Y + Region.Height);

            Native.CombineRgn(DragableRegionNative, DragableRegionNative, RegionNative,
                Region.Draggable ? (int)Native.CombineRgnStyles.RGN_OR : (int)Native.CombineRgnStyles.RGN_DIFF);

            Native.DeleteObject(RegionNative);
        }
    }


    Point dragOffset = new Point();

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            dragOffset = this.PointToScreen(e.Location);
            dragOffset.X -= Location.X;
            dragOffset.Y -= Location.Y;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point newLocation = this.PointToScreen(e.Location);

            newLocation.X -= dragOffset.X;
            newLocation.Y -= dragOffset.Y;

            Location = newLocation;
        }
    }

    void chromewb_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, IsBrowserInitializedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (chromewb.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            ChromeWidgetMessageInterceptor.SetupLoop(chromewb, (m) =>
            {
                if (m.Msg == (int)Native.WM.WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
                {
                    var point = Native.ParsePoint(m.LParam.ToInt32());

                    if (Native.PtInRegion(DragableRegionNative, point.X, point.Y))
                        this.InvokeEx(() => Native.PostMessage(this.Handle, (uint)m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam));

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it is enough to intercept WM_LBUTTONDOWN event from chrome browser, then check if mouse point belongs to a title region and, if so, send this message to main form. As soon as form will get WM_LBUTTONDOWN event, build-in form methods OnMouseDown and OnMouseMove do the other work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: https://github.com/qwqcode/CefSharpDraggableRegion

[image: GIF]

This you can specify `-webkit-app-region: drag` in CSS to tell CefSharp which regions are draggable (like the OS's standard titlebar).