# Draggable borderless window CefSharp C# WinForms

Tags: c#, html, chromium, cefsharp

I can not figure it out.
I have borderless form. How can I make it so that I can move the window (by holding the mouse) for a some div?
Sry for bad english :)

This dont work...Html

```
.title-area 
{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;  
}
<div class='title-area' style="min-width: 100%; height: 40px; background: red;"></div>
```

C#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChromium();
        CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
        chromeBrowser.RegisterJsObject("cefCustomObject", new сefCustomObject(chromeBrowser, this));
        chromeBrowser.MenuHandler = new MenuHandler();
    }

    public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

        String page = string.Format(@"{0}\gui\html\index.html", Application.StartupPath);

        if (!File.Exists(page))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + page);
        }

        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(page);
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
        browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        chromeBrowser.BrowserSettings = browserSettings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draggable borderless window in CefSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053892/draggable-borderless-window-in-cefsharp)

Comment: This code dont work...

Comment: It's the same question regardless.

Comment: which unfortunately did not give a working answer...

Comment: Does it make it any less of a duplicate?